# A ExtJs4 BUG? About FormPanel

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs4

If I set title with FormPanel, Internet Explorer shuts down, but this works on Chrome fine. Can anyone tell me why this happens? Here is the full code:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    alert('1112233');
    Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();
    var main = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        id : "main",
        padding: '0 0 0 50',
        height: 550,
        width: 800,
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            columns: 1
        },
        renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                height: 471,
                width: 632,
                title: 'My Form', //【Here Here ！If do not set Title it's all right】
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working in IE8 and IE9. It should work with IE7 as well.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KK3z2/)

You are missing some thing else. May be typo!